# Unexpected reg (also register) expected end module

Tags: verilog

I´m building a elevator with Verilog with ISE Xilinx. Unfortunately, I got an error:

> unexpected reg (also register) expected end module.

But, I do need the register. Does anyone see the mistake?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
module user_ctrl

          #(parameter FLOORS     = 30,
                      FLOOR_BITS =  5)


          (input  wire                    CLK,
           input  wire                    RESET,
           
           input  wire [(FLOOR_BITS-1):0] CURRENT_FLOOR_IN,           // cabin stage
           input  wire                    HALTED,
           input  wire [(FLOORS-1)    :0] FLOOR_REQUEST,              // floor button pressed
           input  wire                    MANUAL_DOOR_CLOSE_IN,       // close button pressed  
           input  wire                    MANUAL_DOOR_OPEN_IN,        // open button pressed         
           input  wire                    MANUAL_ALARM_IN,            // alarm button pressed

           output wire [(FLOOR_BITS-1):0] CURRENT_FLOOR_OUT,          // forward to cabin display
           output wire                    MANUAL_DOOR_CLOSE_OUT,      // door close cmd
           output wire                    MANUAL_DOOR_OPEN_OUT,       // door open cmd
           output wire                    MANUAL_ALARM_OUT,           // user alarm         
           output wire [(FLOORS-1)    :0] DESTINATIONS,               // destinations
           output reg  [(FLOOR_BITS-1):0] CLEAR_FLOOR_BUTTON,         // reset_button
           output reg                     CLEAR_FLOOR_BUTTON_VALID);  // validate reset_button

/* =============================INSERT CODE HERE======================================*/reg
reg [(FLOOR_BITS-1):0] floor; // sets the register

assign CURRENT_FLOOR_OUT = floor; //allocation of outputs and inputs
assign MANUAL_DOOR_CLOSE_OUT = MANUAL_DOOR_CLOSE_IN;
assign MANUAL_DOOR_OPEN_OUT = MANUAL_DOOR_OPEN_IN;
assign MANUAL_ALARM_OUT = MANUAL_ALARM_IN;
assign DESTINATIONS = FLOOR_REQUEST;

always @ (posedge HALTED)begin //to clear the buttons when elevator is stopped
        floor = CURRENT_FLOOR_IN;
        CLEAR_FLOOR_BUTTON_VALID = 1;
        CLEAR_FLOOR_BUTTON = CURRENT_FLOOR_IN;
    end
    
always @ (negedge HALTED)begin //to let the buttons enlighten when elavator is moving
    CLEAR_FLOOR_BUTTON_VALID = 0;
    end

/* ====================================================================================*/

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `reg` from the end of this line.  Change:

```
/* =============================INSERT CODE HERE======================================*/reg
```

to:

```
/* =============================INSERT CODE HERE======================================*/
```

Comment: Thanks now I see it there was one reg to much.

Comment: @stef if this was the correct answer could you please accept it so others know it has been answered, thanks. and Welcome to StackOverflow.